# IE9 float extra spacing

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, overflow

I have a problem with extra spacing after floated elements in Internet Explorer <= 9.

It is the only browser that renders this page with some **extra** spacing after the HEADER, if some floating is present within (If I remove floating - spacing goes away as well)

I know that I could use `overflow: hidden` and yes, it solves the problem, but in this particular case I **cannot** use it, because I have a drop-down menu in the header. Otherwise, I would have used it already.

I tried using this "clearfix" solution: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/, but it didn't work.

Is there any simple solution without dirty hacks that would fix the issue ?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkg8z/

P.S I'm only interested in supporting IE9 as the lowest version. Everything less can just go to hell

P.P.S

For those, who didn't notice any difference.

[image: Internet Explorer 9]
[image: Opera]

Comment: what do you mean by "extra space"? I just tried the fiddle and it looks ok in IE9

Comment: @jackJoe Can you take a screenshot or something ?
And what I mean by that is the location of the "MIDDLE" sign is pushed down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that since `#content` has `display: table` attribute, `#header` should also have one, according to IE :) 
Crazy stuff.